# JW player react native issue : backgroundAudioEnabled: true not working when playing live video specific in ios

Tags: android, ios, react-native, jwplayer

Below is my code, react native JW player version number 0.2.35 works fine for bacgroundAudioEnabled property, but after updating version to 0.2.37 property bacgroundAudioEnabled not working.

```
<ViewportAwareJWPlayer
    innerRef={(ref) => (jWPlayerRef = ref)}
    style={Style.videoContainer}
    config={{
        license: Platform.select({
            ios: "...",
            android: "...",
        }),
        autostart: true,
        controls:true,
        playlist: [
            {
                mediaId: "0",
                image: WatchVideoData.thumbnail_file,
                time: 0,
                file: WatchVideoData.video_url,
                autostart: false,
                // controls: true,
                repeat: false,
                displayDescription: false,
                displaytitle: false,
                backgroundAudioEnabled: true,
                fullScreenOnLandscape:true,
                landscapeOnFullScreen:true,
            },
        ],
        hideUIGroups: ['casting_menu'],
        backgroundAudioEnabled: true,
        fullScreenOnLandscape:true,
        landscapeOnFullScreen:true,
        styling: {
            colors: {},
        },
        pipEnabled: (platform == 'android') ?  false : true,
    }}
    onViewportLeave={() => {
        jWPlayerRef.pause();
    }}
/>
```

As per my POV audio should play in background.